# How do i show images in ListView?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Private Sub RETRIEVE()
    ListView1.Clear()
    Dim imglist As New ImageList
    imglist.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imglist
    ListView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=images;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim userdataadpter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_img ", connection)
    Dim userdataset As New DataSet
    Dim dt_images As New DataTable
    userdataadpter.Fill(userdataset, "tbl_img")

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt_images.Rows
        Dim img_buffer = CType(dr("image"), Byte())
        Dim img_stream As New MemoryStream(img_buffer, True)
        img_stream.Write(img_buffer, 0, img_stream.Length)
        imglist.Images.Add(dr("image").ToString(), New Bitmap(img_stream))
        img_stream.Close()
        Dim lsvpaarent As New ListViewItem
        lsvpaarent.Text = dr("image").ToString
        lsvpaarent.ImageKey = dr("imageID").ToString
        ListView1.Items.Add(lsvpaarent)
    Next
end sub
```

Comment: Please add some explanation like "what your code does" or "where are you getting issue" and so on.

Comment: i have saved images to a database i want to display the images in a list view

Comment: can u please help me with a code that can be able to retrieve images form sql server in display them in a list view in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're saving images as a byte array in your database and pulling them out, putting them into a imagelist, creating your listview items, then assigning the "ImageKey" to the "ImageId" of the imagelist?

The ImageKey should refer to the index of the item in the imagelist, not some id you have in a database.

See if that works for you.